# How to handle the influx of questions on cheap ways to transfer money from currency A to currency B?

Tags: discussion

There are several of these questions recently and also several older versions of these questions:

- [What is the cheapest way to move money from the United States to Canada?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/51767/what-is-the-cheapest-way-to-move-money-from-the-united-states-to-canada)
- [Most cost effective way to regularly transfer funds from the US to the UK?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/3024/most-cost-effective-way-to-regularly-transfer-funds-from-the-us-to-the-uk)
- [Sending money from Canada to the US](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/5370/sending-money-from-canada-to-the-us)
- [What is the best way of transferring money from American to Canadian bank?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/7593/what-is-the-best-way-of-transferring-money-from-american-to-canadian-bank)
- [Transfer money from Canadian bank account to US bank account while living in the US](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/14670/transfer-money-from-canadian-bank-account-to-us-bank-account-while-living-in-the)
- [Cheapest way to wire or withdraw money from US account while living in Europe](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/37233/cheapest-way-to-wire-or-withdraw-money-from-us-account-while-living-in-europe)
- [How do I find the best exchange rate to convert 1 million Swedish krona into Euros?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/50310/swedish-krona-to-euro)
- [Advice on money transfer from Canada to South Africa](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/39748/advice-on-money-transfer-from-canada-to-south-africa)
- [fastest way to move USD to EUR](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/38853/fastest-way-to-move-usd-to-eur)
- [Most expeditious way to convert EUR to USD?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/20977/most-expeditious-way-to-convert-eur-to-usd)
- [How to send money from europe to usa EUR - USD?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/12005/how-to-send-money-from-europe-to-usa-eur-usd)
- [Money transfer to the U.K](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/13123/money-transfer-to-the-u-k)
- [In Canada, how can I most easily/cheaply send money to a friend online?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/27500/in-canada-how-can-i-most-easily-cheaply-send-money-to-a-friend-online)
- [How to do an international money transfer of a large sum of money to the U.S.?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/5640/how-to-do-an-international-money-transfer-of-a-large-sum-of-money-to-the-u-s)
- [Cheapest USD to GBP transfer](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/50498/cheapest-usd-to-gbp-transfer)
- [What is the the most profitable way of transferring euro to usd in the states?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/50372/what-is-the-the-most-profitable-way-of-transferring-euro-to-usd-in-the-states)
- [How can my friend in the U.K. cheaply transfer money to me in Israel?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/23409/how-can-my-friend-in-the-u-k-cheaply-transfer-money-to-me-in-israel/23410#23410)

There are some nuances between specific countries (e.g. the Norbert Gambit for CAD / USD), but most of the time the answer is to use a forex service.  I feel like it comes up often enough that it deserves a Wiki page even though it is essentially boils down to a product recommendation.  Is this something that is appropriate for the site?

Comment: I noticed the influx as well. The list/summary above is excellent, and will help close some new ones as duplicate, I'd think. Not sure if we have any thoughts on the nature of this influx.

Comment: excellent point. I guess there are quite a few aspects. 1] Should we keep them or close them as product recommendation, if so quite a few would get closed. 2] There are some where although the word cheap/best etc is used, the OP is looking for a method to solve a specific issue so we could keep them open. 3] How do we create a Wiki, is the suggestion that we create a huge answer list for a question "Money Transfer"